# Challenge() always redirects to Login Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to authorize my Action method. Everything works fine but my **Challenge()** method always redirect to **Login Page** even if *I've already logged in*. I try to return **Forbid()** method and it redirects to **Access Denied** page as it should. What might be the problem with Challenge() method ?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
     var project = await _context.Project.Include(p => p.OrganizationsLink).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
     if (project == null)            
        return NotFound();

     //AUTHORIZATION
     var allowed = await _authz.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, new ProjectEditRequirement(project));
     if (!allowed.Succeeded)
        return Challenge();             

     return View(project);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Challenge()` method? We don't know the content inside it which may trigger login page redirection.

Comment: Challenge () method is a method defined in ControllerBase by default with MVC. It's not something I defined myself.

Answer (score 4):

For `Challenge`, it is controlled by `IAuthenticationService`. `AuthenticationService` will call `AuthenticateAsync` to invoke the `handler.AuthenticateAsync()`.

Not sure whether you implement custom `IAuthenticationHandler`, I will go deep the `CookieAuthenticationHandler`.

The complete workflow for `CookieAuthenticaiton` is below:

- `return Challenge()` , for [Challenge](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8311fd870b5594ab547a8cc6ca3b7b87fda9effd/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L2176)

  ```
  public virtual ChallengeResult Challenge()
      => new ChallengeResult();
  ```
- `ChanllengeResult` will call [ExecuteResultAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ChallengeResult.cs#L94)

  ```
   public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
  {
      if (context == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
      }

      var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
      var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ChallengeResult>();

      logger.ChallengeResultExecuting(AuthenticationSchemes);

      if (AuthenticationSchemes != null && AuthenticationSchemes.Count > 0)
      {
          foreach (var scheme in AuthenticationSchemes)
          {
              await context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme, Properties);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          await context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Properties);
      }
  }
  ```
- `context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync` will invoke [ChallengeAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L39)

  ```
   public static Task ChallengeAsync(this HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties) =>
      context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>().ChallengeAsync(context, scheme, properties);
  ```
- For [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a0d6d3e88f974ac8b66890b34d2c28ebd3f25de0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs)

  ```
     protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
  {
      var redirectUri = properties.RedirectUri;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
      {
          redirectUri = OriginalPathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString;
      }

      var loginUri = Options.LoginPath + QueryString.Create(Options.ReturnUrlParameter, redirectUri);
      var redirectContext = new RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Scheme, Options, properties, BuildRedirectUri(loginUri));
      await Events.RedirectToLogin(redirectContext);
  }
  ```

As you could find, the `HandleChallengeAsync` redirect the action.

In my option, you could try return `Forbid()`, otherwise, you will need to override the `HandleChallengeAsync`.

Comment: Shouldn't HandleChallengeAsync contain a code to redirect the user to Forbidden page if the user has already logged in ?  In the documentation it says that it will either redirect to forbidden or login page. But i can't see any place where redirecting to forbidden page is implemented. Did i get the function of this method wrong ?